# Should I re-install certain programs after upgrading from Android 2.1 to Android 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, updates, uninstallation

I upgrade my Samsung Galaxy S phone from Android 2.1 to Android 2.2 over the weekend.

Today, for the first time since buying the phone ( two months now ) **I had to reboot the phone** when starting one of the applications I installed.

This started me wondering **if I should re-install certain programs after an upgrade** ?

Did you had to re-install certain programs after an upgrade ? If so, what programs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to re-install anything. I don't recall any app having an issue from an OS upgrade, except those that needed changes to work with 2.2. Since you're getting 2.2 so long after its initial launch I'd expect all of those issues to already have been worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I installed all the updates that the Market offered me after upgrading to ensure that I had the latest (and presumably most Froyo compatible) versions of my apps, then made sure I had the mostup to date version of my side-loaded apps. Nothing else, and I've had no problems since the upgrade.